# How to get the base pointer of Unicode character?

Tags: java, unicode

Currently I have "codePointAt" which returns the code point of the character from the string.
Is there any API or other way to get the base pointer of the current character?

```
public class Testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String unicodeString = "कागज़";
        int currentPoint = unicodeString.codePointAt(0);

        // Now currentPoint = 0x0915
        // I need currentPoint = 0x0900
    }
}
```

Note# I cannot create the base pointer by addition/subtraction because different language's base point start from different One's/Ten's place values. For e.g.

Armenian - 0530-058F - Base pointer 0x0530(ten's place value)
Devanagari - 0900-097F - Base pointer 0x0900(hundred's place value)

Currently I'm using if-else blocks to get the base pointer which not dynamic and also lengthy approach. :-(

```
int basePointer;
if(currentPoint>0x600 && currentPoint<=0x6FF)//Means Arabic
{
    basePointer = 0x0600;
}
if(currentPoint>0x900 && currentPoint<=0x97F)//Means Devnagri
{
    basePointer = 0x0900;
}
```

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, ICU's [UCharacter.UnicodeBlock.of()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter.UnicodeBlock.html#of-int-) might be helpful.
You will probably need ICU if you are trying to get any specific Unicode data, however I didn't find a method to find the first character in a code block, which is what I understand you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done, thanks to Gábor Bakos for inspiration:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> languageCodePoints = new TreeMap<>();
languageCodePoints.put(0x0020, 0x007E);
languageCodePoints.put(0x00A0, 0x00FF);
languageCodePoints.put(0x0100, 0x017F);
languageCodePoints.put(0x0900, 0x097F); // Devanagri  

// So on for all other languages, referred ISO/IEC 10646:2010 
// for code points of present languages
```

In the function I used this only:

```
String unicodeString = "कागज़";
int currentPoint = unicodeString.codePointAt(0);
int startCodePoint = languageCodePoints.floorKey(currentPoint);
```

Now "startCodePoint = 0x900" which I really required. I think pretty simple way. :-P
Just one thing is that, I have to maintain "languageCodePoints" TreeMap for new language entries but far better than switch/if-else.

Thanks to all for such kind support. :-)

Comment: Whenever a new version of Unicode is released, you can get the official list of blocks from http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Blocks.txt

Comment: @Lithis thank u so much. I was referring ISO/IEC 10646:2010 and seeking something more latest. This is perfect. :-)

Answer (score 3):

OK, after thinking about this for a bit, here is a way to do it just using the Java API.  It consists of three parts:

1. Regenerating the inaccessible block base table [`blockStarts`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Character.java#2560) in [`Character.UnicodeBlock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html) into a `Map`
2. Using [`Character.UnicodeBlock.of(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#of-int-) to look up the block name given the codepoint
3. Using the `Map` to lookup the Unicode block base given the block name

Note that regenerating the block base table is relatively slow at approx 10-15 ms on my machine, so it would probably be best to generate this once and reuse.  I've left the rudimentary timing code in place.

```
private static final int SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_A_BASE = 0x0F0000;
private static final int SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_B_BASE = 0x100000;

private static final Character.UnicodeBlock SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_A =
    Character.UnicodeBlock.of(SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_A_BASE);
private static final Character.UnicodeBlock SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_B =
    Character.UnicodeBlock.of(SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_B_BASE);

public static Map<Character.UnicodeBlock, Integer> makeUnicodeBlockBaseMap() {
  long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
  Map<Character.UnicodeBlock, Integer> unicodeBases = new HashMap<>();
  // Unicode blocks start on 16 (0x10) byte boundaries.
  for (int cp = 0x00000; cp < SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_A_BASE; cp += 0x10) {
    Character.UnicodeBlock ucb = Character.UnicodeBlock.of(cp);
    if (ucb != null) {
      unicodeBases.putIfAbsent(ucb, cp);
    }
  }
  // These blocks are huge, so add them manually.
  unicodeBases.put(SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_A, SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_A_BASE);
  unicodeBases.put(SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_B, SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_B_BASE);
  long endNanos = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.format("Total time = %.3f s%n", (endNanos - startNanos) / 1e9);
  return unicodeBases;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<Character.UnicodeBlock, Integer> unicodeBlockBases = makeUnicodeBlockBaseMap();

  String unicodeString = "कागज़";
  int currentPoint = unicodeString.codePointAt(0);

  Character.UnicodeBlock ucb = Character.UnicodeBlock.of(currentPoint);
  System.out.println(ucb);                                   // DEVANAGARI
  System.out.format("0x%04X%n", unicodeBlockBases.get(ucb)); // 0x0900
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The only thing is that, I have to maintain a storage(table or map or file) for all the language's unicode start code points which makes the approach static. I was thinking maybe there could be an API or something else that I am missing. But finally got that it does not exists. So I created a TreeMap(yes it is static approach since no APIs and better than switch/if-else) and written few line of code to get the base code point. Again thanks for such hardwork. I'll definitely check how to improve my code, from the way you suggested. :-)

Comment: @Aman, not sure what you mean by "static" approach, but this is dynamic in the sense that the table is generated dynamically and does not require any external data (apart from the `SUPPLEMENTARY_PRIVATE_USE_AREA_x_BASE` constants).  It would be quite trivial to wrap this up in some helper methods to make usage simpler.

Comment: There is one table created in "blockStarts". Although I think it contains all the language codes but if a new character range is introduced, it should be added in this table. This is I meant for the static approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the start/end positions to `SortedMap`s for each language and check the codePoints:

```
 private static final SortedSet<Integer, Integer> startToBase = new TreeMap<>();
 private static final SortedSet<Integer, Integer> endToBase = TreeMap<>();
 static {
   // Fill the SortedMaps:
   // latin
   startToBase.put(0, 0);
   endToBase.put(0x00ff, 0);
   // ...
 }
 // Or load this from a web service, table or anything you find comfortable

 public static final int baseCodePoint(int codePoint) {
   // The codePoint should be inserted here (after)
   int baseFromStart = startToBase.get(startToBase.headMap(codePoint + 1).lastKey());
   // the code point should be inserted here (before).
   int baseFromEnd   = endToBase.get(endToBAse.tailMap(codePoint).firstKey());
   if (baseFromStart == baseFromEnd) {
     return baseFromStart;
   }
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(codePoint + " is unknown.");
 }
```

Comment: thanks for another approach but please understand I am seeking a dynamic approach. If, in any case, I have to create database/storage of language codes, in any way, then the solution is not helpful. :-(

Comment: There might be off-by-one errors in the headMap/tailMap parts.

Comment: In that case you should complain about it at the unicode consortium for creating them like this. ;)
Seriously, I think there are databases for this, which you only need to parse proplerly ot use.

Comment: hehe :-D, what I'm thinking is to create a library of this and post somewhere for others to use also because I am not able to find any. :-D

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. I've created a Treemap and got the base code point. Only thing is static approach but it is way more better than switch/if-else. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can use bit manipulation to find the base pointers, something like this:

```
 switch (codePoint & 0xffffff00) {
   case 0x0600: // Arabic
   case 0x0900: // Devnagri, though you might need to check it is below 0x97F
   case 0x0000: // Latin
   default:     // Something else
 }
```

Ah, sorry I think Armenian requires further processing, but hopefully the general idea is applicable for most of the languages.

```
public static int baseCodePoint(int codePoint) {
  switch (codePoint & 0xffffff00) {
    case 0x0900: if (codePoint < 0x0980) return 0x0900;
    case 0x0500: if (codePoint >= 0x0530 && codePoint <= 0x058F) return 0x0530;
    // case ...: other bases where it is not the real base
    // Handling regular base pointers
    default: return codePoint & 0xffffff00;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the Armenian / Devanagari issue is at the hearth of this question.

Comment: Perhaps a list of bitpatterns, with shorter bit patterns first or something like this could be useful?

Comment: Hi @GáborBakos thanks but it will not handle many languages. Also I do not want to write if-else/switch-case for all languages. It is currently I am using which is a static approach. :-(

Comment: Well, the latter option already handles latin, cyrillic, arabic, tibetan and many more.

Comment: @GáborBakos but the solution you provided is using switch-case for which I have to maintain a case table which is not a dynamic approach. So it is not fulfilling the requirement.

Comment: My other solution is more dynamic. (If you create an open source library based on this, could you please link it? Thanks.)